# Subclass in ArrayList<Superclass> method calling issues

Tags: java

I have an arraylist of entities. The Entity class has

```
public void update(int delta, Level level, ArrayList<Entity> entities){
    //do stuff
}
```

a subclass of entity, Player, has a function overriding it

```
public void update(int delta, Level level, ArrayList<Entity> entities){
    //do player specific stuff
    super.update(delta, level, entities);
}
```

when I call the player objects update function from an arraylist of entities, like this:

```
for(Entity entity : entities)            //contains an object of Player
    entity.update(delta, level, entities);
```

it calls the entity function directly and the player specific stuff doesnt happen, however if I call it like this:

```
((Player)entities.get(0)).update(delta, level, entities);
```

it does. I thought I understood the problem but I tried the following code

```
private static class Foo{
    public void print(){
        System.out.println("I AM FOO");
    }
}
private static class Bar extends Foo{
    public void print(){
        System.out.println("i am bar");
        super.print();
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    ArrayList<Foo> foos = new ArrayList<Foo>();
    foos.add(new Foo());
    foos.add(new Bar());
    for(Foo leFoo: foos)
        leFoo.print();
}
```

and it actually calls the print function from Bar when the object is a bar. I'm kinda lost at this point.

Comment: how do you know that `Player.update(...)` is not called when it seems like all that method does is call the superclass version of `update()`?

Comment: it also changes a coordinate and prints "yoo" to the console

Comment: did you accidentally make one or more of those methods static?  also, add `@Override` annotation to the subclass method to ensure it is overriding something in the parent class.

Comment: I'd add `@Override` to the subclass to make sure it is actually overriding the superclass method.

Comment: i added the @Override, eclipsed prompted me to create the function in the super-class, as though i hadn't. when i clicked autogenerate it gave me an error because of a duplicate method. whaat?

Comment: Entity:   http://pastebin.com/LbpxLNDT
Player:   http://pastebin.com/KW18rKgR
Entities: http://pastebin.com/qHC8zRek

Comment: Try creating a `Foo` and `Bar` function that takes in the list `foos` as an argument. See if anything is different. [Recreating a scenario should be very similar to the original problem. You never know where the problem may be coming from.]

Comment: possibly you have some classes where are out of date?  did you try recompiling everything.  and you must have the @Override annotation.  if it won't compile with the annotation, then something is wrong in your code.

Comment: it's a little weird that the Level class seems to come from your "testing" package?  Level seems like it should be part of the "main" api, e.g. in package "game.level".  (you didn't move it at some point, did you?)

Comment: okay. Then I don't know. Its strange to me too. I'll watch this question to learn what the problem may have been.

Comment: yeah, that is werid, now that i look in Entity it doesnt even have an import of level, since its in the same package(game.level). dunno how it got in the paste.
here is the valid paste of Entity: http://pastebin.com/3dQdfPJk

Comment: Oh. Well then that's the problem: There are two `Level` classes, `Entity` uses one, `Player` uses the other, making the method signatures different.

Comment: but the level player uses is a subclass of the level entity uses, shouldnt it still work then?
this is game.level.Level:   http://pastebin.com/K4Gi1hXf
this is testing.level   :   http://pastebin.com/BrFQ6StS

Comment: No, an override can't have parameters that are subclasses of the classes used in the original signature.

Comment: the level that entity uses is an interface, not a class. My bad.

Comment: Think about this this way, what if someone passes a different implementation of `game.level.Level` to `update` -- if `Player` requires a particular implementation, that breaks everything. (A `game.level.Level` is not a `testing.Level`)

Comment: so how should i fix it then? Player doesnt need anything in the specific implementation of the level, he only needs to pass it along to entity
EDIT: fixed it, changed Level level in player.update to game.level.Level

Comment: added answer showing how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have multiple Level classes, you have to ensure that the `Player.update()` method signature references the correct one (in order to override successfully):

```
public class Player {

  @Override
  public void update(int delta, game.level.Level level, ArrayList<Entity> entities) { ... }
}
```

Comment: this is why `@Override` is your friend

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me:

```
List<Entity> fooList = new ArrayList<Entity>();
fooList.add(new Entity());
fooList.add(new Player());
for (Entity entity : fooList) {
    entity.update(1, fooList);
}

private static class Entity {
    public void update(int delta, List<Entity> entities) {
        System.out.println("in Entity");
    }
}
private static class Player extends Entity {
    @Override
    public void update(int delta, List<Entity> entities) {
        System.out.println("in Player");
        super.update(delta, entities);
    }
}
```

Make sure that you need an `@Override` on the `Player.update(...)` method.  It may be that the signatures are not matching so you aren't actually overriding the method signature you think you are.

Couple of other comments:

- Typically when we are dealing with lists we pass around `List<?>` and not the implementation `ArrayList<?>`.
- If you are iterating through the entity list *and* passing it into the method call, you will need to make sure that the update method is *not* changing the list otherwise you will throw an `ConcurrentModificationException`.